# Cannot join a squad in SQDM

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

In a Squad Deathmatch game, (I don't know if this happens on Squad Rush also) when I join I can view the other players on my "squad" team but I am not in the squad, i.e. I cannot spawn on them or view them as green in the HUD, they show up as blue like regular teammates. But I have played games of this gametype where somehow I was able to get on the squad, so that I could spawn with the squad (and do other squad things like see them in the HUD). I actually have no idea what I did, if anything, to get that to happen.

When I go to the squad select menu it displays that I am on the squad and shows me the other players' specializations, and there are no buttons available to me to join the squad.

Anybody know what I'm talking about? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure that this is a known bug (and darn annoying too).

The current work around is to "Switch Teams". When you do this, you will join the squad of the other team you joined. If you are playing with friends, you would then need to "Switch Teams" again.

Of course, when the server is full this doesn't work, as there isn't any room to switch teams.

Comment: Ah I think I remember possibly doing this!! It went and placed me on the squad when I did that. Thanks.